# Can two files have each other as dependencies in Javascript when using webpack?

Tags: javascript, dependencies, webpack

I have a folder `App` that contains:

- `index.html`
- `lib` folder containing my javascript (JS) files

I am using webpack to bundle my JS files, so each JS file requires it's dependencies (other JS files in the same lib folder) at the top and module.exports at the bottom.

`spaceship.js` exports a constructor function Spaceship, and `bullet.js` exports a constructor function Bullet.

I then have a JS file `factory.js` which exports an object called Factory. This object contains a method called createSpaceship, and another called createBullet:

```
// Factory.js
var Bullet = require("./bullet.js");
var Spaceship = require("./spaceship.js");

var Factory  {
  createSpaceship: function() {
    (...)
    return new Spaceship();
  },
  createBullet: function() {
    (...)
    return new Bullet();
  }
}

module.exports = Factory;
```

However, inside of spaceship.js, there is a method called fireBullet, which creates a new instance of Bullet. To do this, I want to require factory.js in spaceship.js. **Is it a problem to have two files requiring each other in this manner?**

```
// spaceship.js
var Factory = require("./factory.js");

var Spaceship = function() {
  //constructor
}

Spaceship.prototype.fireBullet = function() {
  (...)
  return Factory.createBullet();
}
```

I am getting an error in spaceship.js like

> Uncaught TypeError: Factory.createBullet is not a function

I do not know technically how webpack works, and so I can not be sure that this mutual requiring is what is generating the error.

Comment: Wouldn't that be a circular reference, and how would you require something in A from B, that uses A to make B work, when A isn't finished, because it's still using B, which one comes first, the chicken or the egg ?

Comment: Yes, I agree. I just wanted a somewhat technical confirmation that this is in fact so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack handles cyclic dependencies in the same way as Node so they are supported -- see https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html for limitations.

As has been noted cyclic dependencies can generally be avoided by redesigning but you do have two options to fix it given your current design:

```
// Spaceship.js
var Factory = require('./Factory');

function Spaceship(name) {
    // Re-require the factory during instantiation, this works because the factory module has since defined it's export.
    Factory = require('./Factory');
    this.name = name;
}
```

Or alternatively

```
// Factory.js
// Mutate the provided exports object instead of overriding `module.exports`. This works because Node knows what the export will be upfront. NOTE: like the first example the methods will only available in other modules after this module has returned.
exports.createSpaceship = function(name) {
    return new Spaceship(name);
};

exports.createBullet = function(name) {
    return new Bullet(name);
};
```